# change imageview  in android

Tags: android, imageview

I want to show images one by one neither in vertical nor horizontal.

I just created one imageview in xml layout and then i called that image by through id and then i just want to show list of images in one imageview like this.

It first show first image after some time the first image was removed and then second image will be visible with out changing position of imageview like  `ads` in android device. I mean Every 10 seconds the imageview has been changed.

So i tried below code

```
    class doInBack extends AsyncTask<URL, Bitmap, Long>
    {

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... arg0) {
        for(int i=0;i<adimage.length;i++){
            Bitmap  bitmap=Download(adimage[i]);
                publishProgress(bitmap);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 }
               return null;

        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap bitmap) {
             adimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
         }
         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

         }
    }
```

But it didn't call `OnProgressUpdate` method. So please tell me how to show number of images one by one in one imageview.

Comment: Any errors in your code? What's adimage? What's Download(adimage[i])? Your code looks weird for me.

Comment: no errors Download(adimage[i]) means adimage is an array of image urls and in Download(adimage[i]) method it returns bitmap from url

Comment: I don't know if I would trust `Thread.sleep()` that much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code its working

```
                int i=0;
                final Handler  handler=new Handler();
                 final Runnable r=new Runnable()
                  {
                      public void run() 
                      {
                          if(i<adimage.length){
                            adimage.setImageBitmap(Download(adimage[i])); 
                            i++;
                                if(i==adimage.length)
                                    i=0;
                            }
                          else
                              i=0;
                      }
                  };
                  if(thread == null){
                  thread = new Thread()
                  {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          try {
                              while(true) {
                                  sleep(10*1000);
                                  handler.post(r);
                              }
                          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                      }
                  };

                  thread.start();
            }
```